# Context path different of WAR name with Maven

Tags: java, tomcat, maven

I have a web application (WAR) that I want to deploy in Tomcat 5. I'm using Maven 3 and the problem is that when I deploy the WAR, Tomcat automatically copies the context.xml file located in META-INF directory. The file is then renamed with the WAR name and the context path of the application will be the WAR name. By default, it is artifactId-version.war.

The problem is that some client code uses the context path to connect to the web application and I don't want to change the code each time a new version of the web application is deployed. Is there a way to set the context path to another fixed value?

I can't use the tomcat plugin for now. Setting the Context path in the context.xml doesn't help. Also, tomcat documentation precises that it's not recommended to set the Context path in the server.xml. Also, I don't want to change the WAR name, it's important for me to always keep track of the artifact version.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the ${project.build.finalName} parameter in your war plugin config so that you can ensure that the war never changes names.

Comment: I'm not interested to freeze the WAR final name since I want the version to appear in the WAR name.

Comment: Oh, so you want the version in the war name, just not the context name...gotcha.  Not sure you can actually do that if you're not generating the context.xml yourself.

Comment: Have you tried the containerConfigXML parameter in the war plugin's config then?  I've never used it, but it allows you to provide the config for the server...so it should work.

Comment: Yes, but it's only intended to indicate where is the context file in order to place it in the META-INF directory, not more than that.

Comment: Bleh - well that's less than ideal.  I've only gotten this to work by having my war generated without a version in the name.  That won't solve your requirement though.  Would adding the version to the war's manifest (might already be there if you're auto-generating it) and having a war without the version in the name satisfy your needs?